# Spring - How to correctly show relationship data in view (table) using REST api

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, datatable, spring-data-jpa

I have a User (id, username) entity which has **many-to-many** relationship with Roles (id, name) entity. I am trying to show the User data in a ajax Datatable. Now, if a User has six roles, it shows six [object Object] for all six roles. I dont know how to correctly show the role name instead of object Object.

This is what I have:

```
.DataTable(
    {
    "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource" : "/api/AppUser/all",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "aoColumns" : [
    {
    "data" : "id"
    },
    {
    "data" : "username"
    },
    {
    "data" : "userenabled"
    },
    {
    "data" : "useremail"
    },
    {
    "data" : "userfirstname"
    },
    {
    "data" : "userlastname"
    },
    {
    "data" : "useraddress"
    },
    {
    "data" : "roles"
    }
```

This is how it looks like in Data Table:

[image]

Here is my REST [Controller](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootFlashyTemplate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/controller/AppUserRestAPIs.java) piece:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/AppUser")
public class AppUserRestAPIs {
    @GetMapping(value = "/all", produces = "application/json")
    public List<AppUser> getResource() {
        return appUserJPARepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I know it must be trivial but feeling lost and could not find a single example on how to represent relationship data in view (html) using REST api. Searched almost everywhere. What I am missing here? Will appreciate any pointers here.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

Found it ! Here - https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/joinArray.html

So instead of:

```
{
    "data" : "roles"
}
```

I have to use:

```
{
      "data" : "roles",
      render : "[, ].name"
}
```

All worked perfectly but now I am clueless what if I don't use Datatable. Not sure if I have to put another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use function to flat roles list: 
Instead of

```js
{
    "data" : "roles"
}
```

Try this :

```js
{
 "data": null,
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            var flatrole = '';
            //loop through all the roles to build output string
            for (var role in data.roles) {
               flatrole = flatrole + role.name + " ";
            }
            return flatrole;

          }
}
```

Comment: Using above, it shows 6 undefined for each role now. Please suggest

Comment: what is structure of role object ?

Comment: Hemant I put answer myself. But now the question I have is, what if I dont use Datatable?

Comment: I don't understand context. You want an alternative of datatable ?

Comment: Yes correct. An alternative of Datatable, if possible Hemant.

Comment: You can use kendo

Comment: My bad. I should have mentioned no external library. How can we achieve the same with vanilla javascript?